# ORA-24778: cannot open connections

Tags: oracle11g, websphere, database-link

I am getting the `ORA-24778: cannot open connections`, what are the possible causes?
We have a number of applications deployed in WAS7 profile and they connect to a number of schemas in Oracle 11g.

One of the schema is connecting through other schema via public DB link.
I cannot identify a solution for this cause.

After restarting the WAS7 profile, it is ok for a while and again start hitting the error.

Pls help!!

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you've tried. A quick search found a detailed description of ORA-24778, but I can't tell whether you already know what that code means but don't know how it could be happening in this case or whether you don't even know what that error could mean.

Comment: how many connections are you supporting in any/all the connection pools being used?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you missed to tell us a few details:

- You are using XA
- You are using XA in combination with database links
- You are using shared database links
- The ora-24778 is not happening all the time

Either you haven't configured shared server option or you are not connected to a shared server. However Oracle requires you to user shared server if you want to use XA and database links.

Or the parameter **OPEN_LINKS_PER_INSTANCE** is not set sufficiently. Keep in mind mind that there is also a **open_links** init.ora parameter. The open_links parameter does not apply to XA.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you invoke a dblink in a existing transaction.