# DBLinks ORA-24778: cannot open connections

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure which opens the cursor to fetch the data from remote databse

```
 Cursor crs1 is select distinct ID FROM xxxx@link where xxxx and ID = v_id;

Open crs1;
loop fetch crs1 into v_N_ID;
exit when  crs1%notfound;
end loop;
```

This week we started getting this ORA-24778: cannot open connections error. After restarting the websphere server and call the stored procedure it works 2 or 3 times and then again it fails.
We are using XA and the OPEN_LINKS_PER_INSTANCE is set to default 4.

I dont find any answers based on the discussion here
[ORA-24778: cannot open connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771038/ora-24778-cannot-open-connections)

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Most probably you are hitting the instance limit of your database link configuration since it is XA and this is not for a production system.

Comment: you want me to increase the OPEN_LINKS_PER_INSTANCE limit? if we do this may give again an error after it reached the new limit right? Or may be close the link in stored procedure using the alter session?  ALTER SESSION
   CLOSE DATABASE LINK link;

Comment: I've added as comment as a cause of your problem as I don't know which would be the solution, unfortunately.